intelij.docker connection problem in fedora

its the error showing in the Services
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? (Details: [2] No such file or directory)
the error when i run the service:
              r.compose.core.DockerProcessStartException: Unable to start docker process. Is docker correctly installed?
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli$DockerCommands.getDockerCommand(DockerCli.java:140) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli$DockerCommands.<init>(DockerCli.java:129) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli.lambda$new$0(DockerCli.java:65) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1228) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli.<init>(DockerCli.java:64) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCompose.get(DockerCompose.java:92) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeLifecycleManager.getDockerCompose(DockerComposeLifecycleManager.java:154) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeLifecycleManager.start(DockerComposeLifecycleManager.java:110) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeListener.onApplicationEvent(DockerComposeListener.java:53) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeListener.onApplicationEvent(DockerComposeListener.java:35) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.contextLoaded(EventPublishingRunListener.java:98) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$contextLoaded$4(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.contextLoaded(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at com.practice.springsecurity.SpringSeucrityApplication.main(SpringSeucrityApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.ProcessStartException: Unable to start command docker version --format {{.Client.Version}}
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.ProcessRunner.startProcess(ProcessRunner.java:115) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.ProcessStartException: Unable to start command docker version --format {{.Client.Version}}

    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:87) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:74) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli$DockerCommands.getDockerCommand(DockerCli.java:135) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory

    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1170) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1089) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.ProcessRunner.startProcess(ProcessRunner.java:105) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:295) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:225) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1126) ~[na:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

im new to this docker container thing. installed the docker engine , installed the docker desktop and configured some things to use docker without the use of sudo commands and added the user to the group .... did i do anything wrong which caused this ? what im trying to do is run the redis in the docker and use it in my service

Hi! Could you please try to remove the Docker Desktop and Docker Engine you installed and reinstall it using this instruction (only three mentioned steps), and after that, set it up for the non-root user as described here (only four steps)?
